# How do I open a Kotlin/JVM project in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

I am following a tutorial series on YouTube: Kotlin for Beginners. The author is using IntelliJ IDEA for the tutorials and mentions that the work can be done using Android Studio as well. But does mention how to do that. I would rather not download IntelliJ IDEA as I already have Visual Studio 2019 and Android Studio on my laptop; and am running out of space. How can I set up an Android Studio project as if it were a 'plain ole' Kotlin/JVM project?

(I am a month new to software developing overall and don't want to make any permanent, seemingly irreversible or non-simple changes to Android Studio IDE itself.)

I already tried opening an Android Studio project as an Empty Activity, Kotlin, API 21 (Lollipop)

Answer (score 5):

Android Studio has no support for plain Java or Kotlin projects, you can work only on Android projects (Gradle based).

Use IntelliJ IDEA Community or Ultimate for the plain Java/Kotlin projects and other project types.

Comment: Okay then. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @daisukeiga00 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score -1):

Android Studio is based on IntelliJ but limited to Android-Projects (Hence, you cannot open any Non-Android projects in Android Studio). On the other hand, IntelliJ can open any Java/Kotlin project including Android Projects. I would therefore recommend you to uninstall Android Studio from your machine and use IntelliJ instead. In most cases, you will not feel the difference except that IntelliJ can do more that Android Studio can.

Comment: I don't recommend uninstalling Android Studio. There a couple-months lag of bug fixes from Android Studio making it into the Android plugin for IntelliJ. Although I don't remember the exact issue, I remember hunting for a solution for a certain problem for a few hours before I found out it was a plugin bug that had already been fixed in Android Studio.